# How to get props in child component when using spread attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

`Containers` is the child component. I use seperate to pass props to it in parent component.

```
const props = {key:_("containerList"),
                containers: this.state.containers,
                containersStats: this.state.containersStats,
                onlyShowRunning: this.state.onlyShowRunning,
                updateContainers: this.updateContainers,
                updateContainerStats: this.updateContainerStats
            }
        containerList=
            <Containers
                {...props}
            ></Containers>
```

Now I want to get the props in child component `Containers`, how to do that? `this.props.containers`? or `this.props.updateContainers`?

Comment: yes? this.props.containers etc. would return you the props you passed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `spread operator`. It enumerates all your props and pass these props to child component. So in your `<Containers />` component you can access your props like this:

```
const { key,
        containers,
        containersStats,
        onlyShowRunning,
        updateContainers,
        updateContainerStats }= this.props
```

Let me know if you need any further clarification.